# using webpack and babel to transcode es6 files

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, babeljs, koa

I am using koa2 in a web application, for the purpose of study. I've configured the development environment using webpack and babel-loader so that I can write es6 code.

I use sequelize as ORM and I want to load all files under directory /models and init my database. Here is the code

```
fs
  .readdirSync('/Users/zhangfeng/develop/github-ac/models')
  .filter((file) => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== 'index.js');
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    let model = sequelize.import(path.join('/Users/zhangfeng/develop/github-ac/models', file));
    models[model.name] = model;
  });
```

because I run the built code `node build/bundle.js`, so I can just use absolute path, and that works. If there is more elegant way, please tell me :)

while this is not the main problem, I wrote the models inn es6 syntax, it throws error like `unexpected token` because I use `export default` in es6, below is sample code.

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define('user', {
    iNumber: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  })
}
```

which means the files under models/ directory is not transcoded, I know that is because I don't import them any where. for now I have to use `module.exports = blabla` in es5 to make the code work, and this doesn't truly solve my problem. So I want to know how can I transcode them automatically using webpack, or how can I import them dynamically in code.

Comment: What es6 features do you need that isn't available in the latest node?

Comment: as you see, the import and export is not supported, even in node v8.4.0, which annoyed me a lot

Comment: I suggest you to stop using babel and webpack. Just look this will solve all your current issues, and the only downside is es6 modules?
This tools are usefull for browsers, but in node they will only add you problems and unnecessary overhead because nearly all es6 features are already implemented in node

Comment: I saw the [es6 supprt](http://node.green/), and found that I am on the wrong way, you're right, I developed front end before and not so familiar with node.js development nowadays. Thank you very much!